# Identifying a triangle in the 3d-space as acute, obtuse, right or equilateral

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, triangles

> Triangle $ABC$ has vertices $A(-1, 1, 3)$, $B(-1, 3, 5)$, and $C(-3, 3, 3)$.
>  What kind of triangle is $ABC$? Justify your answer.

So far all I have done is I found the distance between $AB$, $BC$ AND $AC$, I do not know whether I should use either the Pythagorean theorem, cosine law or both?

Comment: The Pythagorean Theorem only applies to right triangles.  The law of Cosines works generally, and would let you compute all three angles.

Comment: oh ok thank you so much :) but how do we know that this is not not a right angle triangle?

Comment: @Subi21: if you compute the squared lengths of the sides through the Pythagorean theorem, you may immediately check if your triangle is acute, obtuse, right, equilateral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cosine law is just a generalization of Pythagorean theorem.
 
By just exploiting the Pythagorean theorem we have:

$$ a^2 =BC^2 = 2^2+0^2+2^2 = 8, $$
$$ b^2 = AC^2 = 2^2+2^2+0^2=8, $$
$$ c^2 = AB^2 = 0^2+2^2+2^2=8, $$
and $a=b=c$ gives that your triangle is equilateral.
If you have a bit of visualization skills, you may immediately see that your triangle
 is something like the shaded triangle here:

$\hspace{2in}$[image]